# Coding python on android

Tags: android, python

First of all, sorry. I am new to both programming and programming on my android device, but for some reason when I go to compile this code and run it using Python For Android. It keeps returning this error:

> File "/storage/emulated/programming/pass.py", line 4, in 
>   username = input("Username: ")  File"", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'user' is not defined

```
security = 0

username = ""
while not username:
    username = input("username: ")
password = ""
while not password:
    password = input("password: ")
if username == "user" and password == "pass":
    security = 5
    print (" Hello, security level is:" , security)
else:
    print("invalid login")
```

Now, when I run this same bit of code on my PC, I do not get this error. Is anyone here familiar with writing Python code with Python For Android and Droidedit? I have installed all available modules.

Comment: Try changing `"Username: "` in `username = input("Username: ")` to something else

Comment: @SivaCn no that wont help at all ... he is getting this error because python for android uses python 2.7 (iirc) ... `input` does something very different in python2 vs python 3

Comment: Oh!, @JoranBeasley can you give some link about this ?, it shall help me also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing p4a is not py3.0+  therefore you need `raw_input` not `input`

in python2  `raw_input` is the same as `input` in python3+

using `input` in python2 is the same as doing `eval(input("Username:"))` in python 3

```
>>> x = raw_input("Enter Equation:")
Enter Equation: 5 + 3
>>> print repr(x)
'5 + 3'
>>> y = input("Enter Equation:") #this is the same as eval(input(msg)) in py3+
Enter Equation: 5 + 3
>>> print repr(y)
`8`
```

some further info regarding your error specifically.  in python2 input attempts to evaluate the user input into python code.  you are entering "user" as the username.  python then tries to make it into code interpreting it as a variable.  if for example you entered 543 for the username it would work fine.  also if you entered "user" including the quotes it would work fine as both would evaluate down to python values (the quotes make it a string instead of a variable, and python knows what ints are)

Comment: Thank You so much. This resolved my issue. I wonder why they haven't updated to Python 3+....

Comment: because many packages don't yet support python3, or only partially support it. although more do now ... it prolly is one of those "well it works and it was really hard to get working ... if we switch to python 3 we have to do that all over again"